# how do i write a regular expression using grep to find lines that start with 'O' or 'o' AND contain 2 consecutive chracters

Tags: grep, regular-expression

how do i write a regular expression using grep to find lines that start with 'O' or 'o' AND contain 2 consecutive 'c' characters.

> grep '^[Oo]c{2}' filename

Comment: you must escape the `{}` as `\{\}`

Comment: grep '^[Oo]cc' filename

Comment: i tried doing that @cas it did not work

Comment: You must have mistyped it then, because it certainly does work.  there's no functional difference between `^[Oo]c\{2\}` and `^[Oo]cc`.   e.g. try `grep -c '^[Oo]cc' /usr/share/dict/words`, that will count all words beginning with `Occ` or `occ` (on my system, 123 such words)

Comment: yes i apologize your example did work! but for some reason the given file name i am suppose to use is not displaying the output of the expression.

Comment: do the consecutive 'c' characters have to immediately follow the leading [Oo] ?

Comment: my instructions do not specify. but lets say No. @JeffSchaller

Comment: @agent00uche: in that case, `grep '^[Oo].*cc' filename`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a pure regex answer but here's a more grepish one:

```
grep -i ^occ file
```

The `-i` flag tells grep to do case insensitive matching. It is [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html) so should be present in any grep implementation. Once you have that, since you only want two `c` characters, there's no reason to complicate things by using `{2}`; `cc` is both shorter and clearer. However, note that the `-i` applies to the entire reguex so this will also match `cC` or `CC` or `Cc`. If you don't want that, use [@user454038's approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/234378/22222) instead.

If you also need to match lines where the consecutive `c`s are not directly after the `o`, use this instead:

```
grep -i '^o.*cc' file
```

Comment: `-i` makes the entire regexp case-insensitive, i.e. it will match `CC`, `Cc`, and `cC` as well as `cc`.  If the homework question does not explicitly say that's allowed, the OP will probably be marked down for it.

Comment: @cas good point, answer edited.

Answer (score 5):

You were 99% there, very close, just:

```
grep '^[Oo]c\{2\}' filename
```

or equivalent:

```
grep -E '^[Oo]c{2}' filename
```

### Regular expressions

- as you know `^[Oo]c` , the caret `^` matches beginning, and any of the characters within `[]` are matched
- you were very close with `c{2}`, where you meant to match the previous character `c`, exactly two times.
- however grep by default interprets Basic Regular Expressions which does not interpret `{` as a meta-character for use with this kind of matching, so we change it to `\{` and `\}` to make it recognize it
- alternatively you could enable Extended Regular Expressions to avoid the backslash: `grep -E '^[Oo]c{2}' filename`

If that does not match, maybe copy a sample of the contents of your test `filename` that does include what you are trying to match, and update the question to display it, in case there is something else we missed.

Comment: @agent00uche If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.